# Is the past participle a linking verb in these examples of passive constructions?

Tags: passive-voice, linking-verbs, object-complements, subject-complement

> A man **called** Jack opened the door.

> The man was **called** Jack.

In these two examples, 'called' is a past-participle, and the proper noun 'Jack' is a subject complement that renames the noun 'man'.

This is a common active-voice example:

> They called the man **Jack**.

'Jack' becomes an object complement, and 'called' is a past-tense verb.

In the first two examples, which are passive, is the past participle 'called' also a linking verb, as it doesn't have a direct object and is intransitive? Or do we simply acknowledge that it's in the passive voice (therefore, it has an implied direct object)?

Comment: He is called Jack. We call him Jack. It is an active verb. "called Jack" is an adjective phrase which describes him.

Comment: Your first two examples are ambiguous between passive clauses and complex-intransitive ones. If "called" is intended to have a dynamic meaning then they are passive, more specifically 'short' passives by virtue of not having a _by_ phrase stating an agent. On the other hand, if they have a stative meaning, then "Jack" is a predicative complement in complex-intransitive clauses.

Comment: @BillJ I have found this resource (http://snarkygrammarguide.blogspot.com/2012/09/in-passive-voice-all-verbs-are.html), which says that all passive verb constructions are transitive. I am inclined to agree, but I am interested to hear your thoughts, as I know how fickle these sites can be.

Comment: No, they are intransitive. The effect of switching from the active to the passive is to switch from a transitive clause to an intransitive one: "Pat stole my surfboard" (trans) ~ "My surfboard was stolen by Pat" (intrans).

Comment: @BillJ That makes sense. In reference to your previous comment, is a predicative complement the same as a subject complement? It refers to completing the meaning of the subject, I think.

Comment: @BillJ Also, is it simpler to just say that the verb is passive and leave it as that? Is there any worthwhile knowledge to be gained by breaking it down further?

Comment: Yes, a predicative complement is sometimes called a subject complement or an object complement: "Pat is **very pretty**" (subj comp) ~ "We painted the house **white**" (obj comp).

Comment: General comment: It is best to think of the uses of verbs. Some can only be trans, some can only be intrans, and others (most) can be either trans and intrans. In passives, they are always intrans. For example. in "My surfboard was stolen by Pat", "stolen" is intrans (it has no object) and the whole verb phrase/clause is thus also intrans.